# Prove that $4 + 5 + 6 + \cdots+ n = \frac{n(n+1)}{3}$ for $n \ge 4$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, induction

> Prove using mathematical induction that $$4 + 5 + 6 + \cdots + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{3}$$ where $n \geq 4$ is an integer.

I just wanted to confirm because my Base case P(4) is false. So this statement can't be proven?

Comment: It's not true, so it will be hard to prove it.

Comment: For example, $7(7+1)/3$ is not even an integer. Neither is $4(4+1)/3$. So it can't be true.

Comment: Firstly, if the base case is false, then Mathematical Induction is not applicable (induction says what happens when the base case is true and the induction step is true, it says **nothing** about when one of these is false).  Secondly if the base case is false, then it can be shown (using logic, not Mathematical induction) that the statement is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let´s think a little bit about this:

We know $1+...+n= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ for evey $n \in \mathbb{N}$. So if $4+5+...+n=\frac{n(n+1)}{3}$ for some $n$, we would have

$(1+...+n)-(4+....+n)= \frac{n(n+1)}{2}-\frac{n(n+1)}{3} = 1+2+3=6$

And therefore $n(n+1)=36$.

So we have proven that this is false for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: Disproving for all $n$ is overkill.

Comment: @YvesDaoust But maybe hard to resist.  It's not just wrong - it's very wrong.

Comment: @badjohn: this is to tell the OP that a single counterexample is enough.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I know, I was just being light hearted.  Yours is the more efficient argument but there is a little fun to this one.

Comment: @badjohn  Although your comments made me giggle, I did not mean this to be fun... I just wanted to show that if you want to "prove" something that looks quite like something you already know, then it is probably a good idea to try to write down the connection between these two things.

Answer (score 1):

For $n=4$,

$$4=\frac{4\cdot5}3$$

is blatantly false, hence the claim is wrong. Full stop.

Answer (score 0):

A good principle to go by is "Everything is unknown, until proven or taught otherwise." Another principle is "if something is unknown, then you cannot use it".  And a third principle is "if you cannot use something, try something else".

Induction says that P(n) will always be true if the base case is true and the induction step is true.  What about if the base case is false, well it is unknown whether induction would work, hence we may not use it, hence we should try something else.

Now the eventually goal of such a question is to show that $P$ is always true.  So you wanted to show that $P(4)$ is true, and $P(5)$ is true ect.  You have shown that $P(4)$ is false, hence you have proven that $P$ cannot always be true.